# Automatically play new audio file when music ends

Tags: javascript, audio

I have a JavaScript that I found that picks out a music file at random and then plays it when the site is launched. Now, i was wondering if there's a way to alter the script and make it start a new song when one ends. That way the user don't have to refresh the page whenever the song ends.

This is the code:

```
<script>
var sound1="Music/AnythingGoes.mp3"
var sound2="Music/AWonderfulGuy.mp3"
var sound3="Music/BoogieMan.mp3"
var sound4="Music/ButcherPete.mp3"
var sound5="Music/Civilization.mp3"
var x=Math.round(Math.random()*4)
if (x==0) x=sound1
else if (x==1) x=sound2
else if (x==2) x=sound3
else if (x==3) x=sound4
else x=sound5
if (navigator.appName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer")
document.write('<bgsound src='+'"'+x+'"'+' loop="infinite">')
else
document.write('<embed src='+'"'+x+'"'+'hidden="true" border="0" width="0" height="0" autostart="true" loop="true">')
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

***Edit:***
sample code:

```
    <audio id = 'aud' src = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f9/Beatles_eleanor_rigby.ogg' autoplay></audio>
<script>
    var aud = document.getElementById('aud');
    aud.onended = function() {
        console.log("Track Changing.");
        // aud.src = getRandomSongSrc();
        aud.src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/Ludwig_van_Beethoven_-_Symphonie_5_c-moll_-_1._Allegro_con_brio.ogg";
        aud.load();
    };
</script>
```

### [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9pp890jh/).

in HTML5, you can use a hidden audio element to play the random song, listen to the `ended` event, then call your original function, which would replace the audio element( can be tracked through `id` attribute).

also, instead of  `sound1="Mus ...; sound2 = "...` , you can use `var sounds = [file1, file2..];`, then can reduce if loop to  `x=sound[x];`

Comment: I'm not really sure if i know what you mean. Do you think you could show me an example?